# How to check if the length of an array from api call has changed?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

How Can I check if the length of the array returned after an api refresh call is longer / shorter than the previous value?

for example

```
currentLength;
previousLength;

ngOnInit() {
 this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
   this.data = data;
   this.currentLength = this.data.length;
   // provide check to see if currentLength is different to previousLength

})

this.dataService.getUpdatedData().subscribe();

}
```

Comment: We need more information about your problem

Comment: I've updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.previousLength !== this.currentLength) {
     // Your code

    this.previousLength = this.currentLength;
}
```

On component init, `previousLength` will be undefined so condition will be true

And in that condition only we are assigning previousLength

So the next time condition will work as per your requirement

Comment: should this be called before the call to the service or after?

Comment: What do you exactly want? What I get from you question is, hit an api, and check length of response, if not same do something

Comment: so when i call the api, i want to store the length of the array returned. I also want to store the value of the length of the  previous call.

Comment: does that make sense?